# Cannot find mk package in Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
in Fuerte, the mk ROS package cannot be found.
I.e. it is located in `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/mk/` and there is a `manifest.xml`
file in this directory but it is not added in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` in `/opt/ros/fuerte/`.

```
 $ rospack find mk
 [rospack] Warning: ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/ros is not a directory
 [rospack] Error: stack/package mk not found
```

Did anyone experience the same issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32701/cannot-find-mk-package-in-fuerte/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to file system hierarchy changes, the Fuerte environment is set up differently. You can't just substitute `fuerte` for `electric` in a customized setup script.

The correct setting for `$ROS_ROOT` is `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros`.

You can `source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash` directly when running with the Ubuntu install packages.

For building against that with custom overlays, I recommend [`rosws`](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html), a new command in the `rosinstall` package. It will build custom setup scripts and keep them up to date. It works fine for Electric workspaces, too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-04-26**:
Thanks! It fixed the issue. I will try rosws :)